# How to convert swap partition from RAID1 to RAID0 using mdadm

Tags: linux, partition, mdadm, optimization, operating-system

How to convert linux SWAP memory from RAID1 to RAID0?

**Start with**:
2 exact size swap formatted partitions (*/dev/sdc5* and */dev/sdd5*) on 2 physically separate disks that are used via Software RAID
(*named md127, located /dev/md/s*) in **RAID 1** (Mirroring)

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

would show for **md127** something like:

```
md127 : active raid1 sdc5[2] sdd5[0]
      7806976 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

**The task is to use the same**:
2 exact size swap formatted partitions (*/dev/sdc5* and */dev/sdd5*) on 2 physically separate disks that are used via Software RAID
(*named md127, located /dev/md/s*) in **RAID 0** (Striping)

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

would show for **md127** something like:

```
md127 : active raid0 sdc5[2] sdd5[0]
      15613952 blocks super 1.2 64k chunks
```

> Convert **SWAP** /dev/md/s from **RAID1** to **RAID0** with **mdadm**

For this you need to know:

- the difference between RAID0 and RAID1
- when the Operating System uses SWAP partition (*for ex: when you are about to run out of free available physical memory*)
- how to monitor the memory usage (via a tool like **conky**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please find below a simple way to achieve the requested.
> I did not really need help. Mostly sharing to whoever it might help.

To start you may want to check the details of **/dev/md/s**

```
sudo mdadm --detail /dev/md/s
```

Then "grow" the RAID to RAID0.
This will loose one partition, but that's ok with us:

```
sudo mdadm /dev/md/s --grow --level=0
```

Then add the missing partition back using the command below. This will temporary change to a RAID4 and convert to RAID0 when completed

```
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md/s --raid-devices=2 --add /dev/sdc5
```

To check progress you could use:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```